# OpenID connect access token to authenticate my own REST api

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-page-application, openid, openid-connect

If I authenticate with OpenID connect, I can authenticate my SPA ok.
How do I use the obtained access token now to access my own REST resources?

It's a simple question, but I don't find satisfactory answers.
A prominent answer I always find is 'use oidc when you don't have a backend'.
Now that makes me wonder if ever a webapp was created that didn't need a backend.
Oidc is almost always the answer when the question of storing a refresh token in the client pops up (like in 'use oidc, it's a better architecture and ditch the refresh token') but it doesn't really explain anything.

So when the user logs in with, say Google, he obtains an identity and an access token (to ensure that the user is who he claims he is).
So how do you use this to authenticate at your own REST service?

The only real way I see it as stateless is by sending another request at the server to the provider on every request to the REST api, to match the identity to the validity of the access token there.
If not, we fall back to the good 'ol session vs jwt discussion, which doesn't quite seem to click with the oidc because now we're duplicating authentication logic.
And the good 'ol refresh token in the browser is generally promoted as a bad idea, although you can keep access tokens in the browser session storage (according to the js oidc client library), autorefresh them with the provider and that's fine then (-.-).

I'm running again circles.
Anybody can lay this out for me and please break the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SPA (frontend) needs to add an authorization header with access token to each API request. Frontend should implement the authorization code flow + PKCE (implicit flow is not recommended anymore) + it needs to refresh access token.

Your API (backend) needs to implement OIDC (or you can use "oidc auth" proxy in front of backend) - it just validates access token, eventually returns 401 (`Unauthorized`) for request with invalid/expired/... token. This token validation is stateless, because it needs only  public key(s) to verify token signature + current timestamp. Public keys are usually downloaded when backends is starting from OIDC discovery URL, so they doesn't need to be redownloaded during every backend request.

BTW: refresh token in the browser is bad idea, because refresh token is equivalent of your own credentials

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to answer this! This could simplify any of this a lot, if I can just validate the oidc access token without network requests in my api gateway. Is there a known resource available that I can use to implement oidc verification in my NodeJS backend? (I find it pretty difficult to find resources online).

Comment: I think this will help: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth Should be enough to do the implementation. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Trace https://openid.net/developers/certified/ is good starting point, when you are looking OIDC libraries